# Opening Youtube video in media player by getting the URL from the webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I connect to a youtube video page from a webview. I can get the rtsp link of the video from here and I want to open it in native media player. But here the problem is: I want to trigger the opening of the media player when the user wants to play the video, when he/she clicks the video. How can I listen to that?

Comment: After loading youtube url,click on any video you will see video playing in the media player by default,you do not have to keep listener for the video click.

Answer (score 0):

Below code open your video in native media player.

```
   String url = "Rtsp Link";
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url,"video/*");
   startActivity(intent);
```